# Procurar primeiro Elemento dentro de outro Elemento se existe em jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou com um problema de encontrar um Elemento dentro de Outro e verificar se ele é primeiro elemento, veja a estrutura:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="teste1" placeholder="Texto">
  <label for="teste1">Texto</label>
  <p class="help-block">Teste.</p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Texto</label>
  <p>Texto</p>
  <p class="help-block">Teste.</p>
</div>
```

Estou querendo selecionar a tag `label` dentro do `form-group` mas só se ele for o primeiro elemento, tentei desta forma em `jQuery`:

```
if ( $('.form-group').children().first().is('label') ) {
  $(this).parent().css("padding-top", "0");
}
```

Mas a resposta é `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.form-group')` retorna um array contendo todos os elementos da classe.

```
$('.form-group').each(function() {
    var primeiro = $(this).children().first();
    if($(primeiro).is('label')) {
    $(primeiro).parent().css('padding-top', '0');
  }
});
```

exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/re7ktwaq/

Comment: Eu imaginava que o `jQuery` depois do `$(document).ready` lido ele conseguiria buscar os elementos, nem acreditei que precisava de passar numa array primeiro, valeu pelo exemplo.